# Adding apostrophe to tinymce special characters

Tags: html, tinymce, special-characters

im trying to add apostrophe '(&#39 &#x27) to tinymce custom character insert tab.

As I found out, I had to edit javascript file located in tinymce folder: tinymce\themes\advanced\js\charmap.js

Characters are added in this format:

```
['x', 'y', bool, 'desc']
```

The x is the html code, the y is the unicode character, the bool is whether to display or not, the desc is a description.

I am having trouble adding apostrophe
`['&#39',     '&#x27',  true, 'apostrophe']` (removed **;** for display) which appears in the following section but when I select it and save it, it is no longer in the content.

[image]

Am I providing incorrect character codes? I tried to add right single quote `['&#8217',   '&#x2019',true, 'right single quote']` and it works correctly, does not dissappear after saving.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: did you try to use the javascript character notation?  i.e. '\u202F'

Comment: No, could you show example with that?  [x , y , bool , desc]